# Why doesn't Google Translate by Speech function on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

I videoed this hitch on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/DK9HUKJUEr0). As you can see, I disabled extensions and plugin.

But Google Translate by speech doesn't look to be working? [Step 3](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142468?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) never happens:

> 3. When told to "Speak now," say what you want to translate.

Comment: are you sure that chrome/firefox browser recognizes that you have plugged in mic in your pc?

Comment: @user0 How can I check this please?

Comment: https://www.podcastinsights.com/online-mic-test/ or https://webcammictest.com/check-microphone.html or https://www.onlinemictest.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue! Microphone didn't work on google translate site and on the main google page clicking on mic have been produced *No Internet connection* output. How I solved it: I downloaded the google-chrome-stable version from the official source [download google chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and installed it. Now the microphone on google translate and other services is working as expected. Side note: I have latest Chromium browser as well on my Linux and mic *does not* work here.