# Why doesn't the Speaker icon on Google Translate appear on Firefox?

Tags: google-translate

I opened the  Firefox browser beneath in Safe Mode, to eschew Add-ons. Why's the "Speak" icon missing? It appears [on my Chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/118931/72255).

[image]

Comment: I’d say that it has more to do with the browser (plugins and/or settings) than with the service itself, because while I can reproduce the issue, it doesn’t happen on the same machine in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex But I tried "in Safe Mode" (as I wrote)?